# How to deploy .war file in tomcat7 along with JDBC jar ?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, jdbc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a war file in tomcat7. I am using MySQL JDBC driver to connect to database server. The jar file of MySQL JDBC driver is copied to `$CATALINA_HOME/lib/` directory and the web application works correctly.

Now, I want to deploy the .war file in Amazon Elastic BeanStalk service. By default, Amazon doesn't place the MySQL JDBC driver in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` directory by default and I can't run a script which will ssh into each instance and download the jar in the directory.

Is there any way, in which I can bundle the jar file for JDBC driver , so that I don't have to download and place the jar file in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` directory ?

Comment: If Tomcat runs nothing else, would it be an option to put the jdbc driver in your WAR file?

Comment: Yes, Tomcat doesn't run anything else. I am just deploying one war file in Tomcat.

Comment: Then just bring in the driver in your war file.  Will most likely make your daily work easier too as your deployment is selfcontained.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The jar file for JDBC is already a part of the war file, and is there in WEB-INF/lib folder, but still I need to put the same jar file in $CATALINA_HOME/lib/ folder.

Comment: You don't need to do that, depending on how you create connection. How are you configuring and creating connections?

Comment: I am using DBCP connection pool to create connections.

Comment: Ok, but are you using an in-code (or maybe spring-config) configured DBCP pool, or are you depending on Tomcat configuration for DBCP? In the first case, a library in `WEB-INF/lib` can be used, in the second case it can't be used.

Comment: I am using tomcat configuration for DBCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No you can't bundle JDBC JARS for Tomcat7:**

I've had this issue and it was a nightmare to debug. In my trials and in the documentation you can't bundle JDBC drivers inside your WAR file. Or at least you can but the classloader will ignore JDBC classes that are not in the Tomcat Lib folder. Its in the first paragraph of the Mysql section of the documentation here -> [Tomcat7-JDBC](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL%20DBCP%20Example) I don't know of Tomcat8 or Tomcat9 beta...

**Short Term Solution**

What I do is exactly what you said you don't want to do and similar to Mark B's solution. I use a script that copies it from s3 but this is really easy and is only 1 line of bash if you use the aws s3 cp command. The aws s3 tool comes installed on the EC2 instance your application will be running on.

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/mysql.jar /usr/share/tomcat7/lib/mysql.jar
```

*You will need to restart tomcat another reason you should see the longterm solution

**Long Term Real Solution = Automate Your Build Steps**

In the end you'll eventually have to run provisioning scripts if your application becomes complex, which is why I stopped using elastic beanstalk and started using AWS cloudformation which gives you a "STEP" where you can throw in all your setup scripts similar to docker build steps. It will also run those configuration steps for every new instance that gets created so there is no needed for you to ssh onto every box.

Cloudformation is all about turning your infrastructure setup into code which you could actually check into github and build without any manual intervention. You go through the headache of configuring your build scripts once then save your environment as a json or yaml file. You can include the MySQL server, tomcat version, firewalls, load balancers etc etc and build that all from a file.

Answer (score 2):

You can place the jar file in an S3 bucket, and then use a [EB container command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) to copy the file to the lib directory, like:

```
"copy-lib-file":
  mode: "000644"
  owner: root
  group: root
  source: https://s3.amazonaws.com/<MY_BUCKET>/<my-JDBC-driver>.jar
```

Comment: Will it work, when say the load on web app increases and elastic beanstalk uses auto scaling to create new instances automatically ?

Comment: Yes, the whole point of doing it this way is to tell Elastic Beanstalk how to setup each new server it creates.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try this solution

Comment: This doesn't work , even after downloading the jar file in the correct location, I am unable to use JDBC. It gives the same error as before. Although, the file is downloaded at the correct location, I probably need to make sure that tomcat7 is restarted , after the file is downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat, like many application servers, installs a variety of class loaders (implementation of java.lang.ClassLoader) that will give your application access to the JDBC jar resource.

The order is:

1. Bootstrap
2. System
3. Common - $CATALINA_BASE/lib
4. Webapp - /WEB-INF/lib

Put the jar into the **WEB-INF/lib** directory inside the application. Note, this JAR will be only visible to this specific application and no others.

Comment: I have already tried this, but it doesn't work. Tomcat7 doesn't use the jar kept in WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: If Tomcat is configured to delegate the class loading, it will load from System and Common first. To prioritize loading from the Webapp, set delegate to false.

<Loader delegate="false"/>

Comment: "It doesn't work" sounds like you are doing something wrong.  Please provide more details.

Comment: I mean that when I don't put the jar file in /$CATALINA_HOME/lib directory, I get the exception `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found`

Answer (score 1):

In order to do so you need to use .[ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html).
With .ebextensions you can copy files from your application package to the beanstalk file system.

However keep in mind that no other application deployed in a beanstalk environment will use your driver. Your beanstalk instance is dedicated to one application. Every time you upload the application you have to upload the mysql driver in order to be deployed to the tomcat installation.

Therefore you do not gain anything in terms of upload size or memory footprint in a tomcat (shared jdbc connetion pool through jndi).

It seems that uploading your application with the jdbc driver included (non provided in your maven config) is a more beanstalk oriented solution.

However there are cases you don't want to make any changes in the way your war gets packaged, for example your application gets deployed to an on premises tomcat server containing the jdbc driver and you want to upload it to an elastic beanstalk environment.
In such cases you can consider [docker with elastic beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html) as an option too.

Comment: I only need to run one application on Elastic beanstalk, so that won't be a problem for me. Docker with elastic beanstalk would also be a suitable solution for me. Thanks for answering

Comment: The least painful solution is to package the jar with your application.
Using .ebextensions would be a painful solution (depends on beanstalk experience).
Using docker is much more painful so it might not be an option.

Comment: Yeah, but packaging the jar with war file doesn't seem to work for some strange reason with mysql-connector (although it should work), and I am not able to figure out why.

Comment: I see. It seems that your real problem has to do with the jar not packaging. Unfortunately the least painful solutions require packaging the jar inside the war. It would be a good idea to create an issue with the jar packaging problem.

Comment: Nope, I have seen the contents of the war file and the mysql-connector jar file is properly packaged into the war file